# Get id of first input inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
 <div id="div-1"> 
<input id = "input1" >
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var list = document.getElementById("div-1").firstChild.id;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

The output i get is

```
Undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct property you have to use is `firstElementChild`

```
var list = document.getElementById("div-1").firstElementChild.id;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/u2q7jpk0/

Answer (score 8):

The [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)(which retrieve the first child node) may be the text node just before the input element(whitespace) and it doesn't have any `id` property so the output would be `undefined`.

To resolve the problem, use [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to get the input element or use [`firstChildElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)(not widely supported, which retrieves the first child element) property.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("div-1").querySelector('input').id;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <input id="input1">
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

```js
var list = document.getElementById("div-1").firstElementChild.id;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <input id="input1">
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

**UPDATE :** Or you can directly select the element with [`Document#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method.

```js
// you can use css selector with querySelector
// which only gets the first element from them
var list = document.querySelector('#div-1 input').id;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <input id="input1">
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer is:

```
var inputID = document.querySelector("#div-1 input").id;
```

Because `querySelector` returns the first node that matches the provided CSS selector. You can essentially find just the one element you need rather that finding the `div` and then looking for its first child.

This is simpler and will perform better.

```js
var inputID = document.querySelector("#div-1 input").id;
document.getElementById("demo").textContent = inputID;
```

```html
<div id="div-1"> 
  <input id = "input1" >
  <input id = "input2" >
  <input id = "input3" >
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need element you could use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`

```js
var list = document.getElementById("div-1").firstElementChild.id;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

```html
 <div id="div-1"> 
<input id = "input1" >
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Or you could use `#div-1 > *:first-child` to select first child element whatever it is.

```js
document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML =
    document.querySelector('#div-1 > *:first-child').id
```

```html
<div id="div-1"> 
    <input id = "input1" >
    </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Why not just `document.querySelector("#div-1 input").id`?